# what is logic behind this java code

Tags: java

I came across below java line and puzzled about its output. Can you please explain me logic behind this code

```
System.out.println((int)(char)(byte) -1);
```

Output:

```
65535
```

Comment: The logic is to confound and confuse. ;) If you ever write code like this its worth commenting why you did it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, it's equivalent to:

```
byte b = -1;
char c = (char) b; // c = '\uFFFF' - overflow from -1
int i = c; // i = 65535
```

Really the explicit conversion to `int` in the original is only to make it call `System.out.println(int)` instead of `System.out.println(char)`.

I believe the `byte` to `char` conversion is *actually* going through an implicit widening conversion first - so it's like this really:

```
byte b = -1;
int tmp = b; // tmp = -1
char c = (char) tmp; // c = '\uFFFF'
```

Does that help at all?

Comment: Thanks Jon. I understood that. Just one more doubt. If i put       System.out.println((char)(byte) -1);  then it's displaying "?". Any reason

Comment: Does this mean `char` is unsigned in Java? Which makes it the only unsigned primitve.

Comment: @Sukumar: That's because the character `0xFFFF` is not recognized by the console.

Comment: @Martijn: Yes, you're absolutely right about `char` being the only unsigned primitive in Java.

Comment: @Jon: Are booleans signed? :)

Answer (score 5):

it's the same as

`System.out.println((int) '?');`

- `(byte) -1` gives: -1
- `(char) -1` gives: ?
- `(int) '?'` gives 65535

Answer (score 1):

In java `byte` is a signed (twos-complement) 8-bit primitive type. The binary representation of a `byte` with a value of -1 is `11111111`. This then gets cast to a char which is a 16-bit primitive with a value between `\u0000` and `\uFFFF` (0 and 65535) - it would appear that the bits of the byte are left-shifted by 8, with sign-extension. So at this point the binary representation is:

```
1111111111111111
```

...or 65535. However, it is then not quite as simple as saying "Oh yes then it is turned into an `int` so we don't see the character representation and is printed out". In java, all numeric primitives are signed! If we cast the char as a `short` which is another 16-bit primitive, the program would output `-1`. However, when we cast it to a 32-bit `int`. The final binary representation becomes:

```
00000000000000001111111111111111
```

...which is 65535 both signed and unsigned!

Comment: `In java, all numeric primitives are signed` - No. The whole point of this exercise is to show that chars are unsigned in Java. Otherwise the result would be 0xffffffff and NOT 0xffff..

Comment: @Voo Yes, `In java, all numeric primitives are signed`, by that I mean all primitives except chars, which do not represent numbers (kind of, maybe that was a bad choice of words..). I don't understand the second part of your repsonse, the result isn't 0xffff?

Comment: Ah ok, I'm just used to handle chars like any other primitive without a distinction (too much C?) but I can see how that's valid. The second part just meant that if chars weren't unsigned we'd get 0xffffffff instead of 0xffff.