# Can anyone explain the logic behind it

Tags: java

what would be the output of

1).

```
     int j=0;
     for (int i=0; i<100; i++) j=j++;
     System.out.println(j);
```

I thought `j=j++;` will be equal to

```
 int j2 = j;
    j = j+1;
```

so I was expecting the out put would be 99. but when I compiled on eclipse output was 0.

2). and I could not understand what is the logic behind

```
  ((int)(char)(byte) -1)
```

When ran it on eclipse I got output as 65535.

Comment: it should go in code.stackexchange

Comment: 1. One question per question please. 2. Try to give your question a name that describes the problem.

Comment: Duplicates: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2750216/1343161  2. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7500523/1343161

Comment: J++ is the same as j = j +1

Comment: I do not want to be rude, but I think most of these things are nicely explained in the Internet, and in most programming books. If you want to learn a programming language, it is definitely helpful to read a related book. StackOverflow's is a place to discuss more serious (or should I say, advanced) matters. Learn the basics and try again. You may find programmers.stackexchange.com also useful. You should also check the terms of use in the help center for both programmers and SO

Comment: Surely..I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5):

```
j=j++;
```

is functionally equal to

```
int xxx = j;
j++;
j = xxx;
```

So the value of `j` stays the same. (Because the right side is evaluated first, including the increment, then the result is assigned to `j`)

As for `((int)(char)(byte) -1)`, a char is 16bit in size and unsigned, so the bit pattern of -1 results in 65535.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the ++ works as follows:
`a = 0;`
`a = a++; // a will get the assignment of the current value of a before the increment occurs` so a = 0 in here

However, in the next case here:
`a = 0;`
`a = ++a; // a will get the assignment of the incremented value of a` so a = 1 in here